# Fast big matrix generation

Tags: r, performance, matrix

I want to generate a big matrix mat=`matrix(, nrow=1e6, ncol=1e4)`. The value of `mat` are assigned as `mat[,1] = 1:1e6`. For columns `cols in 2:1e4`，`mat[,cols] = mat[,1] + shift[cols]`, where `shift` is a numeric vector, for e.g., `shift = runif( 1e4 )`.

There are many ways to do this. The problem is that, this is a frequently called part of another function. The computational time will largely increase if this part is inefficient. Any one have good suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: See if `big.matrix()` in `bigmemory` works for you

Comment: What ways have you tried? I think `sweep` is very efficient, something like `sweep(m, 2, shift, '+')`.

Comment: I think there's a solution using `outer` , since `outer` can use any user-defined function to create the output data.  lemme think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
frist<-1:10
addto<-runif(5)
outer(frist,addto,'+')
```

Now a time trial:

```
frist<-1:1e5
addto<-runif(1e3)

carl<-function(frist,addto)  outer(frist,addto,'+')

konvas<-function(frist,addto) {
fristmat<-matrix(rep(frist,times=length(addto)),nr=length(frist))
sweep(fristmat, 2, addto, '+') 
}

microbenchmark(carl(frist,addto),konvas(frist,addto),times=5)
Unit: seconds
                 expr      min       lq   median      uq
   carl(frist, addto) 1.046612 1.052813 1.053038 1.05717
 konvas(frist, addto) 7.265776 7.302062 7.328859 7.35135
      max neval
 1.344122     5
 7.366162     5
```